# Oscillator with non-linear damping / drag equation

Tags: drag, oscillators, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

For linear damping

$$ \ddot{y} + 2\beta_0 \, \dot{y} + \omega_0^2 y = 0 $$

the solution with initial conditions $y(0) = y_0, \; \dot{y}(0) = 0$ reads

$$ y(t) = y_0 \, \sec\delta \, e^{-\beta_0 t} \, \cos(\Omega t - \delta) $$

with

$$ \Omega^2 = \omega_0^2 - \beta_0^2 $$

$$ \tan \delta = \frac{\beta_0}{\Omega} $$

For non-linear damping

$$ \ddot{y} + 2\beta \, \dot{y} + \omega_0^2 y = 0 $$

with a speed-dependend drag coefficient

$$ \beta = \beta(|\dot{y}|) $$

we have different regimes, especially

$$ \beta \simeq \beta_0 \quad (\text{Stokes}) $$

$$ \beta \simeq \beta_1 |\dot{y}| \quad (\text{Newton}) $$

An interesting observation from experiments with spheres of mass m with weak damping is that for $|\dot{y}|$ in the range up to the Newton regime a fit with the ansatz

$$ y(t) = y_0 \, \sec\delta \, e^{-\beta_\text{eff} t} \, \cos(\Omega_\text{eff} t - \delta) $$

works quote nice. $\beta_\text{eff}$ is only slowly varying, and $\Omega_\text{eff}$ is constant over large time scales; there's no drift in the period $T = 2\pi/\Omega$, derived from the zeros of $y(t)$.

However, for the fitted parameters one finds

$$ \beta_\text{eff} \gg \beta_\text{Stokes} $$

$$ \Omega^2 + \beta_\text{eff}^2 < \omega_0^2 $$

And there's no obvious relation between $\beta_\text{eff}$ and the function $\beta(|\dot{y}|)$, of course.

**Questions**:

Is there an Ansatz for $y(t)$ which allows one to guess a kind of perturbation series, and from which this "Stokes-like" behavior can be derived?
Is there an Ansatz which allows one to "integrate out" the fast oscillations from the non-linear differential equation? (I doubt this is possible b/c the fast modes appear in $\beta$). Is there an Ansatz how to derive $\beta_\text{eff}$ from a full model of $\beta(|\dot{y}|)$?

I am not interested in the numerical solution for $y(t)$ and parametric fits for $\beta(|\dot{y}|)$. I know how that works - and it does not explain why this quasi-Stokes behavior occures.

Comment: An adiabatic approximation/series, starting from either regimes, should be doable.

Comment: My Ansatz for the adiabatic approximation would be $e^{-\Gamma(t)} (\cos(\Omega t + \delta(t))$, where both $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are slowly varying functions. Is it that, what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm saying. The point is to set up a perturbation series in the derivatives of $\Gamma(t)$ and $\delta(t)$ but it may require to adjust your problem a bit. Do you have an explicit form for your $\beta$?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of models, partially based on physical considerations, partially just to fit the data: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drag_coefficient_of_a_sphere_as_a_function_of_Reynolds_number.png
I think $C_D(Re) = c_0 / Re + c_1 + \ldots)$ will do for the first steps, that means $\beta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 u + \ldots$. Looking at the data $\phi=0$ is a good starting point. I have to work on the adiabatic aproximation first.

Comment: Remark: I am looking for a generic approach that does not depend on the specific form of $\beta(u)$.

Comment: The truly classic monograph KRYLOFF and BOGOLIUBOFF: INTRODUCTION TO NON-LINEAR MECHANICS, PRINCETON UNIVERSITY PRESS,1947 deals specifically with your problem; see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogoliubov_averaging_method.

Comment: @hyportnex – great, thanks a lot; looks as if this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: see also https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Krylov-Bogolyubov_method_of_averaging and references therein.